# Connectedness of set of critical points if every critical point is a global minimum

Tags: calculus, general-topology, optimization

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^n\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ is a smooth function whose global min is denoted as $f^*>-\infty$. If any critical points of $f$ is a global minimum, is it true that the set of all critical points of $f$ is a connected set? If not, is there any counterexample?

Comment: I guess I understand what you mean now, but perhaps you want to change your question to "if every critical point is a global minimum".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $f(x,y)=(x-1)^2(x+1)^2e^y$, then

$$\nabla f(x,y)=(2(x-1)(x+1)2xe^y, (x-1)^2(x+1)^2e^y)$$

So the critical points are exactly the two parallel lines $x=1, x=-1$, and all are global minima.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, given by
$$
f(x) = (x-1)^2 (x+1)^2.
$$
The set of critical points is $\{-1,0,1\}$ which is not connected.

[image]

Comment: _If any critical points of $f$ is a global minimum_.

Comment: There are two critical points that are global minima.